# Action Bar buttons not showing on Text Selection in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am using edittext widget in android for text editing but when i select the text in edittext the app bar shown above donot have button visible to copy and paste i can access them by touching but they are not visible because of the app bar color. how can i make them visible.

[image: Screen shot of my app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the app theme or create a custom style and specify the background or text.color to the color you want, and in your theme xml resource file, between the "style" element, set the "android:actionBarStyle" to the custom style you just created, it'll change the color for you.